# HLOOKUP in multiple excel sheet

Tags: excel

Having one sheet as below:

[image: img]

Second sheet as below:

[image: img]

I need to use HLOOKUP for finding the Date in the column.Someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `VLOOKUP` not `HLOOKUP` for this task.

Use `=VLOOKUP(B11,$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)` and drag it to right or `=VLOOKUP(B11:D11,$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)` to fill all row at once.

If your first table is in another sheet, instead of range to look in `A2:B6` use `Actual_Sheet_Name!$A$2:$B$6`

Result:
[image]